# UIImage not shown as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

```
- (void)showImageAtTableView:(UITableView *)tableView     forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows].count) {
        if ([[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]       indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound) {
        //cell is expanded
        CGFloat frameHeight = [[self.widthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
        CGFloat frameWidth = [[self.heightArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
        //CGFloat yOrigin = [self configureHeightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0,
                                       12,
                                       frameWidth,
                                       frameHeight);
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.jpg"];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        //configue which cell
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    }
}

}
```

the code above is supposed to add a UIImageView to an existing UITableViewCell when tapped. this is the line that call that method (showImageAtTableView:forRowAtIndexPath)  :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self updateTableView];
    //get and show the image at selected cell
    [self showImageAtTableView:tableView forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

but this is the result when the tableviewcell is tapped:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c652Y.png

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not changing the height of the `UITableViewCell`.

I think a better approach would be to include the `UIImageView` in the `xib` / `storyboard` design. Assuming you have some kind of `dto` object storing the data showed in the cells, you can keep on them a `boolean` indicating whether or not the image should be showed.

- On your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you'll update that `boolean`, and do a `[tableView reloadData]`.
- In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you'll hide / show the `UIImageView` according the `boolean`.
- In your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you'll check again the boolean value in order to update the height accordingly.

Hope it helps.